# How to cron run every 1 hour on ubuntu 9+?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

How to start a script using `cron` every hour?

Answer (score 15):

0 * * * * should work and will run at every 1 hour

0 1 * * * will run at 1 AM in night every day..

Answer (score 6):

Put your script in /etc/cron.hourly.

Comment: 0 */1 * * * ~~

maybe?

Comment: Nope, 0 * * * * or @hourly or like I said, put it in your cron.hourly directory.

Comment: but it will work in ubuntu?
i'll try it tomorrow, thx ;]

Comment: Also, make sure your script file name does not contain a period (.) - see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692253

Comment: yes it works in Ubuntu.